# Difference between duplicated options in Close and Flag dialogs

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close, close-reasons

After getting the 3000 reputation required to cast close votes I noticed that a number of the options in the close dialog duplicated options that are already in the flag dialog.

#### For example

I've got three options for reporting a duplicate question:

> [image: Three "Duplicate Question" Options]

**Do any of these do the same thing as the others?**

Or perhaps, is closing as a duplicate equivalent to flagging *and* closing whereas flagging as a duplicate is solely a flag?

If closing is equivalent to flagging and closing, then **shouldn't flags automatically include a close vote** (after the privilege is earned), to both save clicks and reduce the size of the review queue? (Would there ever be a case when you would want to flag but not vote?)

Some (but not all) other options are also available in both dialogs. (For example, *spam* and *rude or abusive* do **not** appear in the close dialog.

---

Also (kinda related), one of the last 3 options in the close dialog (can't remember which atm and don't wanna flag to find out) gives no warning/confirmation which wouldn't matter except that it also doesn't allow it to be retracted (like all the other options).

Comment: Once you've earned the close vote privilege (3k on SO) flagging to close  doesn't do any flagging - it's converted directly to a close vote.

Comment: @JonClements ...so then the **`Flag`** dialog serves no purpose except for **`spam`** and **`rude`** (since I *can't* close as those), correct?

Comment: Please note I used the flag -> should be closed-> duplicate

Comment: you can use flags for comments or answers or as you said spam and rude/abusive posts

Comment: @ashleedawg you use flags for anything that *isn't a close* reason - so spam, r/a, vlq, "other"... etc... If you use that dialog to flag something for closure, it'll just become a vote anyway...

Comment: @SurajRao - so now the **`close`** dialog shows **1 flag** as duplicate but the **`flag`** dialog **shows zero**.  Shouldn't they both show 1?

Comment: also, shouldn't `spam` also get flagged for closing (or are those handled differently, like internally by S.O. staff?)

Comment: vote != flag... 5 close votes closes a question and places it on hold. A flag _to close_ will push it into the Close review queue and will not count as a vote. Flagging by a low req user on a post which already has close votes is useless. So no the flag indicator doesnt show 1 flag.. its a vote

Comment: As for spam flag, the post is deleted and other action may be taken on user account.. It is not closing either

Comment: @SurajRao -**`if [reputation]>3000 then [close button]=[flag button] else [close button].visible = false`** ,  according to @jon-clements (first comment)

Comment: not exaclty.. close button == flag->should be closed section

Comment: ...so @JonClements is mistaken?

Comment: @ashleedawg Why are your code bolded?

Comment: @user202729 - In Western typography, the general technique of a change or modification of font (generally **boldface**, *italics* and sᴍᴀʟʟ ᴄᴀᴘs) is called **[emphasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_(typography))**; the strengthening of words in text with a font in a different style from the rest of the text, to **highlight** or *bring attention* to them.